# Put integer into quotes in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this variable

```
DECLARE @MultipleTicketTypeId nvarchar(200) = (SELECT Id FROM #Table1 WHERE Name='Multiple')
```

and i want to compare that value with @TicketTypeId in

```
CASE 
    WHEN SUM(FSBT.[RealMoneyBetAmount]) = 0 THEN 0                                        
    WHEN @TicketTypeId = @MultipleTicketTypeId THEN SUM(ISNULL(T1.[DecimalOdds],0) * T1.[RealMoneyBetAmount])  /  SUM(T1.[RealMoneyBetAmount])
    ELSE ''-1''
```

but i get error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to int

Can someone help me ?

EDIT: One more thing that i forgot it: @TicketTypeId will be always in '2' format , so with quotes and @MultipleTicketTypeId is without for now, but should be with ''

Comment: try casting your nvarchar as int before comparing

Comment: just compare it with a casted value instead of the original value....`when cast(@Tickettypeid as int)=@multipletickettypeid`

Comment: One more way is to use `select Concat('''',Id,'''') from #tabel1`

Answer (score 1):

First, fix the `CASE` so all return values are numbers.

Second, do the comparison as a *string*, not a *number*:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(FSBT.[RealMoneyBetAmount]) = 0
      THEN 0                                         
      WHEN CAST(@TicketTypeId, nvarchar(200)) = @MultipleTicketTypeId
      THEN SUM(COALESCE(T1.[DecimalOdds],0) * T1.[RealMoneyBetAmount]) / SUM(T1.[RealMoneyBetAmount])
      ELSE -1
 END)
```

When given values of different types, SQL Server has to figure out how to do the comparison.  For a string and a number, it converts the string to a number.  The safest thing is just to do the comparison as a string.